# JQuery fadeTo lagging

Tags: jquery, fadeto

Im using JQuery fadeTo effect to change an image's opacity to 0.2 on mouseover and change it back to 1 on mouseleave. The problem that I encounter is that whenever I trigger the mouseleave event the image has 0.2 opacity for a few seconds before returng to opacity value of 1. It's like I'm using the delay function but I don't. Any tips appreciated. Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
         $('.projectboxright').mouseover(function(){
              $('.projectboxright .projectimage').fadeTo(300,0.2,'easeOutQuad');
         });

         $('.projectboxright').mouseleave(function(){
              $('.projectboxright .projectimage').fadeTo(300,1,'easeOutQuad');
         });
});
```

Comment: Can you run the Firebug perf. profiler on your site and share the results? (I'm wondering if there is other JS on your page that is slowing you down...)

Comment: It says "No javascript errors"

Comment: No the profiler. You start the profiler, do your fading and then stop the profiler. It gives you a breakdown of the time it takes to execute each command.

Comment: Do you have the `easeOutQuad` easing function actually installed?  If not, then your animating will jump and you won't see proper animation.  `swing` and `linear` are the only two easing functions installed by default with jQuery.

Comment: @levib Are you looking for this? http://pastebin.com/mSHJyNhe
And yes I have the easing functions installed (JqueryUI), I'm using it for other animations too and it works fine.

Comment: That is what I was looking for. Indeed it appears that you are lagging quite a bit with that call but it is at the very most taking up just a quarter of your JS processing time. Are there any functions on the page that could be processor heavy? Do you get the same lag in different browsers?

Comment: I have just two other similar animations and only this one is lagging. I've tried it in Chrome and Opera and the results are the same.

Comment: How many `.projectboxright .projectimage`s are being animated?

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot Only one because i have a .projectboxleft .projectimage selector for the other image that is animated.

Comment: Mmm, the problem's not weight of numbers then. Do ...left and ...right images behave the same? If not, then what's different? Is ...right more deeply nested or more deeply layered, for instance? And does the problem disappear on a high spec computer? I'm thinking graphics card performance here.

Comment: Yes they behave exactly the same, they are positioned fixed and are not depending on any other element. I've tried it on a a little bit more powerful graphics card than mine and there is a slight improvement but it's still a lag.